# Nameserver regular expression improvements

Tags: regex

I have the following simple regular expression for nameservers:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.]+
```

I would like to improve this by

- Limiting the number of . in the last portion to a maximum of 1 (to
  allow for .co.uk, but restricting invalid domains)
- Not allowing the first section to be www

Can anyone provide some assistance?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent domain owners from using www in their DNS server name?

Comment: @tripleee Can nameservers be www.domain.com? I was under the impression they couldn't.

Comment: There are no special constraints on nameserver names whatsoever. It would be somewhat unwise and unconventional to use a name like that, but there is no sane reason to disallow it, and it might actually be useful for two domain owners to agree to run a name server for each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]*\*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2,3}$` will match:

- 3 or 4 components separated by `.`
- Each component consists of one or more alphanumeric character
- The first component may also contain up to one `*`

Not allowing the first section to be www is messy to do all in the same regex, and probably better done as a pre/post step with the equivalent of `if (!string.startsWith("www"))` in whatever you are using.

Comment: @Alex I may have misunderstood you, but if you want this to match a string like `*.whatever.co.uk` you can just add `*` to the first character class: `[a-zA-Z0-9*]`. Note there is no `\ ` required because the `*` is inside the class.

Comment: How would I limit the * to a maximum of 1 within that first portion?

Comment: Sorry, what if it was ns*.domain.com (limiting to 1 in this instance

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I am not familar with what constitute a valid ns string. :) Does the * have to be the last character or can it be anywhere in the first component?

Comment: Anywhere within the first component

Comment: @Alex Hmm getting a little messy now but: `([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]*\*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)` will match a non-empty string with up to one `*`.